# how to use docker build nginx

Tags: docker, nginx

I'm using docker build nginx container. this is my code (line breaks added for readability)

```
docker run -it -p 8082:80 --name nginx-test \
  -v ~/nginx/www:/usr/share/nginx/html \
  -v ~/nginx/conf/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf \
  -v ~/nginx/logs:/var/log/nginx nginx /bin/bash
```

my development environment is centos7 in vmware 
and i find the result is docker's nginx.conf file become directory in my linux 
why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$HOME` instead of `~` and it will work:

`docker run -it -p 8082:80 --name nginx-test -v $HOME/nginx/www:/usr/share/nginx/html -v $HOME/nginx/conf/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf -v $HOME/nginx/logs:/var/log/nginx nginx /bin/bash`

Or use absolute path i.e. `/home/<user>/...` in volumes.

Comment: sorry,I tried it，but if not have nginx.conf file in $HOME/nginx/conf/ directory ,it will  return info :docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:424: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting \\\"/root/nginx/conf/nginx.conf\\\" to rootfs \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/82f7b963749f1800dba73adeb498b9158845171baa48b5f04a3a588b0d2f99a2/merged\\\" at

Comment: \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/82f7b963749f1800dba73adeb498b9158845171baa48b5f04a3a588b0d2f99a2/merged/etc/nginx/nginx.conf\\\" caused \\\"not a directory\\\"\"": unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type.so is use absolute path ...but if i add nginx.conf file in my path .when i change this file ,docker's nginx.conf  will not change

Comment: You have to make sure that `nginx.conf` exists at your host `$HOME/nginx/conf/` directory. This is the core file without Nginx won't start.

Comment: ok,so when i change nginx.conf in the host  $HOME/nginx/conf/ but docker's nginx.conf will no change.i have a idea is when nginx.conf in the host  $HOME/nginx/conf/ are change ,i have to delete existing nginx docker container and rebuild it ensure nginx.conf synchronization ,but in fact that's not reasonable,is it?

Comment: Yes. Mounting `nginx.conf` to the container will automatically reflect the changes in the container when you edit at the host.